# Setting up angular 5 + express typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, angular5

I would like to setup a new application made in angular 5 and express (express in typescript as well).

Is there any guide you can suggest me to achieve my goal?

Many thanks in advance, 
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your talking about **Angular 5** frontend and **Node express REST API**

#### BACKEND

You should search for *typescript node express REST* starters on **github** for the backend part setup. I've also created one such starter with `mongoDB` and basic `JWT` authentication here [typescript-node-rest-starter](https://github.com/maljukan/typescript-node-rest-starter).

#### FRONTEND:

Generate a project using `angular-cli` and then just find some examples and tutorials of consuming the REST API by Angular 2+ application. There is an ocean of resources [here](https://angular.io/resources)

Comment: Hello, many thanks. Isn't there any chance of having server and client in one single project?

Comment: @user2357805 This doesn't make sense, because Angular project contains client-side code and backend project is... backend. They have different dependencies sets, purposes - everything. You just need to be sure that Angular dist will be copied to public folder on build.

Comment: Although the subject of your question is Angular 5, the answer is the same as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676616/can-angularjs-be-used-without-a-rest-api It's not what it's made for so i think using it without REST API makes no sense to me.

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/DavideViolante/Angular-Full-Stack
Seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: That's exactly the example of what @estus and i said. Notice that it's not one project but a bundle of two separate projects.

Comment: @maljukan Not exactly, this is a single project with one package.json - likely angular-cli project where server-side items were added. I would warn agiainst this approach, it's impractical.

Comment: I agree with estus. The very nature of web apps implies that you have at least two applications. This forced decoupling can be painful, but since you have no choice, you gain nothing by recoupling them arbitrarily with a toolchain.